# How to access keys in dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pickle, dictionary-comprehension

Being a beginner in python, I was working with a CSV file and created an edge list such that the values have a one-to-one mapping with the values of that line in the CSV, like:
Output:

```
value1 value2     
value1 value3
value2 value3    
value4 value5
.
.
.
```

Then I assigned unique numbers to each of these values in the csv file such that the unique number acts as the key and the item in the CSV acts as the value like in a dictionary. Also if any value gets repeated in the CSV file, I don't want to assign another key to it.

Output:

```
dictionary=
{
1: "value1",
2: "value2",
3: "value3",
.
.
.
}
```

Now I want the Edge list (that I have created earlier) as the output but The values in the edge list should be replaced by their keys in the dictionary, like:

```
1 2
1 3
2 3
.
.
.
```

Thank You!

Comment: Please add the code you have used so far so we can help you to fix the issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the main issue here is when building the dictionary from unique numbers to names since I feel you should build it the other way around (from names to unique numbers). Also, when this map is built, you are missing the code to convert your mapping to the final mapping with unique numbers.

Find below my proposed code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                                                                   

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# For better print formatting
from __future__ import print_function

# Imports
import sys


#
# HELPER METHODS
#

def mapping(csv_filename, mapping_filename):
    if __debug__:
        print("CSV File: " + str(csv_filename))
        print("Mapping File: " + str(mapping_filename))

    # Retrieve data from CSV file
    with open(csv_filename, "r") as csv_file:
        data_raw = csv_file.readlines()
    data = []
    for line in data_raw:
        line = line.strip()
        elements = line.split(",")
        elements = [e.strip() for e in elements]
        data.append(elements)

    # Create mapping list and file
    mapping_list = []
    with open(mapping_filename, "w") as mapping_file:
        for elements in data:
            j = 0
            while j != len(elements) - 1:
                for k in range(j + 1, len(elements)):
                    # Add to mapping
                    temp = [elements[j], elements[k]]
                    mapping_list.append(temp)
                    # Write to file
                    mapping_file.write(elements[j] + " " + elements[k] + "\n")
                j += 1

    # Return the mapping
    return mapping_list


def build_key_map(mapping_list):
    if __debug__:
        print("Mapping List: " + str(mapping_list))

    key_dict = {}
    i = 1
    # Check each parsed node inside each edge
    for edge in mapping_list:
        for node in edge:
            # Add node to keys if it has not been registered yet
            if node not in key_dict.keys():
                key_dict[node] = i
                i = i + 1

    return key_dict


def build_graph(mapping_list, key_dict):
    if __debug__:
        print("Mapping List: " + str(mapping_list))
        print("Key Dict: " + str(key_dict))

    # Copy the existing mapping changing each node (inside edge) by its unique number
    new_mapping_list = []
    for edge in mapping_list:
        new_edge = []
        for node in edge:
            new_edge.append(key_dict[node])
        new_mapping_list.append(new_edge)

    return new_mapping_list


#
# MAIN
#

def main():
    import sys
    csv_file = sys.argv[1]
    mapping_file = sys.argv[2]

    mapping_list = mapping(csv_file, mapping_file)
    key_dict = build_key_map(mapping_list)
    new_mapping_list = build_graph(mapping_list, key_dict)

    print("FINAL MAPPING: ")
    for edge in new_mapping_list:
        print(edge)


#
# ENTRY POINT
#

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Notice that I have tried to preserve your code in separate functions although having all the process in a single function may increase performance:

- The `mapping function` parses the CSV file and produces a map (list of edges from node to node) and writes it to a given file. Here, the CSV parsing is split by "," (like the example you provided) although your original code was splitting it by ":".
- The `build_key_map` creates a dictionary from node names to unique numbers.
- The `build_graph` converts the mapping with node names using their unique number.

Using your input, the expected output is:

```
> python parser.py "csv.txt" "map.txt"
CSV File: csv.txt
Mapping File: map.txt
Mapping List: [['man', 'nut'], ['man', 'bag'], ['nut', 'bag'], ['rat', 'cat'], ['dog', 'fog'], ['dog', 'cat'], ['dog', 'man'], ['fog', 'cat'], ['fog', 'man'], ['cat', 'man']]
Mapping List: [['man', 'nut'], ['man', 'bag'], ['nut', 'bag'], ['rat', 'cat'], ['dog', 'fog'], ['dog', 'cat'], ['dog', 'man'], ['fog', 'cat'], ['fog', 'man'], ['cat', 'man']]
Key Dict: {'nut': 2, 'dog': 6, 'cat': 5, 'bag': 3, 'rat': 4, 'fog': 7, 'man': 1}
FINAL MAPPING: 
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[2, 3]
[4, 5]
[6, 7]
[6, 5]
[6, 1]
[7, 5]
[7, 1]
[5, 1]
```

Also, I have added some comments but let me know if I need to clarify some part.

**EDIT:**

By the way, if you really need to have the map from unique number to value you can always invert the dictionary and store it while the algorithm can keep working with the dictionary from names to unique numbers. To invert a dictionary you just need to:

```
inverted_dict = dict([[v,k] for k,v in key_dict.items()])
```

**EDIT2:**

I provide here another version of the mapping function that directly generates the mapping with unique values (instead of using several functions and intermediate structures).

```
def mapping(csv_filename, mapping_filename):
    if __debug__:
        print("CSV File: " + str(csv_filename))
        print("Mapping File: " + str(mapping_filename))

    # Retrieve data from CSV file
    with open(csv_filename, "r") as csv_file:
        data_raw = csv_file.readlines()
    data = []
    for line in data_raw:
        line = line.strip()
        elements = line.split(",")
        elements = [e.strip() for e in elements]
        data.append(elements)

    # Create mapping list and file
    mapping_list = []
    key_dict = {}
    unique_num = 1
    with open(mapping_filename, "w") as mapping_file:
        for elements in data:
            j = 0
            while j != len(elements) - 1:
                for k in range(j + 1, len(elements)):
                    if __debug__:
                        print("Converting: " + elements[j] + " -> " + elements[k])
                    # Transform elements to keys
                    if elements[j] in key_dict.keys():
                        key_j = key_dict[elements[j]]
                    else:
                        key_dict[elements[j]] = unique_num
                        key_j = unique_num
                        unique_num = unique_num + 1
                    if elements[k] in key_dict.keys():
                        key_k = key_dict[elements[k]]
                    else:
                        key_dict[elements[k]] = unique_num
                        key_k = unique_num
                        unique_num = unique_num + 1
                    # Add to mapping
                    if __debug__:
                        print("Adding: " + str(key_j) + " -> " + str(key_k))
                    mapping_list.append([key_j, key_k])
                    # Write to file
                    mapping_file.write(str(key_j) + " " + str(key_k) + "\n")
                j += 1

    # Return the mapping
    return mapping_list
```

Its expected output is:

```
> python parser.py "csv.txt" "map.txt"
CSV File: csv.txt
Mapping File: map.txt
Converting: man -> nut
Adding: 1 -> 2
Converting: man -> bag
Adding: 1 -> 3
Converting: nut -> bag
Adding: 2 -> 3
Converting: rat -> cat
Adding: 4 -> 5
Converting: dog -> fog
Adding: 6 -> 7
Converting: dog -> cat
Adding: 6 -> 5
Converting: dog -> man
Adding: 6 -> 1
Converting: fog -> cat
Adding: 7 -> 5
Converting: fog -> man
Adding: 7 -> 1
Converting: cat -> man
Adding: 5 -> 1
FINAL MAPPING: 
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[2, 3]
[4, 5]
[6, 7]
[6, 5]
[6, 1]
[7, 5]
[7, 1]
[5, 1]
```

Comment: @Rocky4 I understood that is what you were asking for. Let me know if I missed something.

Comment: Is it possible without the use of these functions and rather keep it a individual program codes? The problem is then I will have to change considerable amount of my code to accommodate your program!
Also how do I read the dictionary file to make the final edge list?

Comment: The first two functions were already provided by you so you can just add the code of my EDIT2 to a single file and run it to have individual program codes.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't manage manually indices in loops (`while(j!=len(i)-1)`) unless you have no choice.

For the combinations, you can use `itertools`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.combinations(["man", "nut", "bag"], 2))
[('man', 'nut'), ('man', 'bag'), ('nut', 'bag')]
```

It's then easy to get the edges.

I create a reader for the example you gave:

```
>>> data = """man,nut,bag
... rat,cat
... dog,fog,cat,man"""
...
>>> import io
>>> import csv
>>> reader = csv.reader(io.StringIO(data))
```

The edges are the concatenation of the combinations for each row:

```
>>> edges = [(v1, v2) for row in reader for v1, v2 in itertools.combinations(row, 2)]
>>> edges
[('man', 'nut'), ('man', 'bag'), ('nut', 'bag'), ('rat', 'cat'), ('dog', 'fog'), ('dog', 'cat'), ('dog', 'man'), ('fog', 'cat'), ('fog', 'man'), ('cat', 'man')]
```

Now you can extract unique elements from `edges`:

```
>>> vs = sorted(set(a for e in edges for a in e))
>>> vs
['bag', 'cat', 'dog', 'fog', 'man', 'nut', 'rat']
```

(I use `sorted` here to get a reproducible result, but you don't need it). To give number to every vertex, just use the indices in the list:

```
>>> list(enumerate(vs))
[(0, 'bag'), (1, 'cat'), (2, 'dog'), (3, 'fog'), (4, 'man'), (5, 'nut'), (6, 'rat')]
>>> i_by_v = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(vs)}
>>> i_by_v
{'bag': 0, 'cat': 1, 'dog': 2, 'fog': 3, 'man': 4, 'nut': 5, 'rat': 6}
```

Let's replace vertices by their number:

```
>>> [(i_by_v[v1], i_by_v[v2]) for v1, v2 in edges]
[(4, 5), (4, 0), (5, 0), (6, 1), (2, 3), (2, 1), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 4), (1, 4)]
```

Now you can use every graph algorithm you want.